# Cyclomatic Compleity IF ELSE vs SWITCH CASE

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement, sonarqube, cyclomatic-complexity

Many code analysis tools like sonar throw errors for switch case if used instead of multiple is-else for cyclomatic complexity . Is there a number which should be a threshold of when one should use if else and when one should use switch case ?
Say if its a case of 50 , to reduce cyclomatic  complexity one should use switch case ? Would be good if you could support your answer with an example ?

Comment: If there are 50 possible branches for an input, the code requires some hard refactoring.

Comment: It can be 50 cases of matching and then setting a particular value ?

Comment: It shouldn't be. Chances are some design decision went wrong. But if there are really so many possible branches, use deterministic automaton and value will be calculated with CC = 1. Or some key value value structure i guess, like anything that implements Map interface.

Comment: That makes sense but is there a number which tells when we should use switch and when if else ?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question with another question.

Would you rather read:

```
if(cond1)..

else if(cond2)...

else if(cond50)...

else ...
```

or

```
value = map.get(key)
```

If there are so many possible cases, than neither the switch or if seem appropriate and should therefore be replaced with `key-value structure` or `state machine pattern` - if branching is really complicated.

You can find an example implementation here:

[fsm](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/state/java/5)

As to when to use if or switch, keep in mind that switch cannot accept the following types:

`long`, `double`, `float`, `boolean` so when you have such an input, switch is obviously not a choice.

I wouldn't use number as a metric to use `switch` or `if statement`. There is one exception however, if an input can have only 2 possible values it is better to use if. Even Sonar should suggest you this.

That said, `switch` is usually more readable than the series of if statements. As an important decision factor, other than readability, within switch statement there can be groups of values which might require same execution path. It is basically safer version of the `goto`. Unlike if, where each outcome is usually bound to specific execution path.